# Node.js Modules for Amazon SES

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Are there any Node.js modules for [Amazon Simple Email Service](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/)?

> Amazon Simple Email Service (Amazon
>   SES) is a highly scalable and
>   cost-effective bulk and transactional
>   email-sending service for businesses
>   and developers.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was mentioned in the node.js mailing list yesterday: https://github.com/mrduncan/aws-lib/tree/ses-secure.

Answer (score 5):

[Amazon has an official AWS SDK for Node.js](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornodejs/).

You can install it by doing

```
npm install aws-sdk
```

See [documentation here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/frames.html).

Answer (score 3):

Specifically for SES on node you can use this:

https://github.com/jjenkins/node-amazon-ses

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to set up an SMTP endpoint.

This way, you can use any SMTP library, like [emailjs](https://github.com/eleith/emailjs), and things will route through Amazon SES: http://aws.amazon.com/ses/faqs/

> **Q: Does Amazon SES provide an SMTP endpoint?**
>
> Yes. Amazon SES provides a full-featured SMTP interface for seamless
>   integration with applications that can send email via SMTP. You can
>   connect directly to this SMTP interface from your applications, or
>   configure your existing email server to use this interface as an SMTP
>   relay.
>
> To connect to the Amazon SES SMTP interface, you must create SMTP
>   credentials. To create your credentials, go to the Amazon SES console
>   and [click the SMTP link](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ses/home#smtp-settings).

Comment: Thanks! This has the added benefit that AWS credentials are not required. Only SMTP credentials are needed.

Comment: This needs more upvotes. Works with SMTP credentials, which is a feature most modules lack.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use AwsSum which has implemented many of the Amazon Web Services, as well as others:

- https://github.com/appsattic/node-awssum/tree/master/lib/amazon

AwsSum also helps you along a little but more than those other modules but it's worth trying them all to see which one you like. :)

(Disclaimer: I'm the author of AwsSum so I'm biased.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is **aws-sdk** and **node-ses** are one of the best module to send email using SES.

***NPM AWS-SDK*** 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk

***AWS-SES-MAIL*** 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-ses-mail